# Setting up Firebase Android chat

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to create a chat room using Android Studio and Firebase,
I noticed that Firebase, provided an [example project](https://github.com/firebase/AndroidChat) into GitHub website.

I read that I have only to change the string with the correct database name. I receive a toast message that is "Connected" to Firebase server, but I can't see any messages.

Is there something missing?

Comment: You're likely connecting to a new Firebase project, one that is created on firebase.google.com. Such projects require that the user be authenticated, which the AndroidChat sample doesn't handle. Your best bet to getting started with a Firebase chat app is by taking the [Android Codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-android/).

Comment: I used the same project about 1 month ago with a different project, and still works without any authentication

Answer (score 0):

The project that you have downloaded is the starter project for the codelabs to work with, you should do along with that tutorial to achieve the application to work,
Otherwise you can download the finished project from this github repository,[firebase chat](https://github.com/firebase/friendlychat)

In this repository, import the android project below android start and change all the package names , copy the googleservices.json that you will get by creating new project in your firebase account, and also change the url which you will find inside project with firebase url. Then it will work succesfully :)
[Firebase Registration](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup)